# How to process image data from post request in node without express/multer?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to submit a POST request with an image to an azure functions endpoint. The endpoint is going to upload the image to azure blob storage. Everything is hooked up, but I'm not sure how to process the form encoded image data to be uploaded to the blob storage account. I'd like to avoid adding express and am looking for alternatives to multer. I've tried consulting the documentation, but it also uses express/multer.

Below is what I have so far for the azure function. It's currently able to upload it to the azure storage account, but the data is not correct since I cannot display when I try to download it or view it.

```
export const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    const storageConnectionString = config.storageConnectionString;

    // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);

    // Create a unique name for the container
    const containerName = config.storageContainerName;

    // Get a reference to a container
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    const blobName = context.bindingData.imageName;

    // Get a block blob client
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    if (req.method === "POST")
    {
      const content = req.body;
      const blobHeaders: BlobHTTPHeaders = {
        blobContentType: "image/jpeg",
      }
      const options: BlockBlobUploadOptions = {blobHTTPHeaders: blobHeaders};
      const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(content, content.length, options);
    }

};
```

Here is my request from postman removing the token and the path to image.

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:7071/api/images/jaimeLannister.jpg' \
--header 'Cookie: BL_SiteLanguageID=1; __RequestVerificationToken=TOKEN' \
--form 'image=@/C:/jaimeLannister.jpg'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any particular reason for not using a blob output binding in your Function?

Comment: Also i see you're using `--form` in your curl request, that would be a multipart upload, you probably want to remove that and add `-H "Content-type: application/octet-stream"` instead if you only want the JPEG payload in your body (since you have this in your code `const content = req.body`).

Comment: I'm pretty new to azure functions and don't understand bindings very well. There's other operations like verifying image size, checking the file name, would I be able to configure this with a blob output binding?

Comment: When I didn't specify the blobContentType it defaulted to application/octet-stream, but I was unable to view the image in azure storage so I tried changing it to image/jpeg. The -- form came from how I was sending the request in postman. I believe that's how it's going to come in from the front end. I appreciate the feedback so far!

Comment: [Imperative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime) should give you full control over the name for a blob output binding. To parse the multi-part either [use a library](https://github.com/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser) or roll your own (which i strongly discourage since multi-part looks trivial but it's a trap). If could also not do multi-part and do `application/octet-stream` from the frontend instead and send the filename as a header in the POST request.

Comment: I'm looking for a library to use, but I'm using typescript/javascript. It seems the most widely used option is multer, but essentially I'm just looking for the ReadFormAsync as defined here. https://blog.rasmustc.com/multipart-data-with-azure-functions-httptriggers/ .  I also tried formidable, but the request types are different between the http trigger request and formidable request.

Comment: [This example](https://medium.com/@rkmusic75/uploading-image-multipart-to-azure-blob-from-azure-functions-streamifier-parse-multipart-79d9d679adef) uses [`parse-multipart`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart) from npm which seems to be a more lightweight alternative to formidable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As wvilSnobu said, you could use [`parse-multipart`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart) from npm which seems to be a more lightweight alternative to formidable.

Refer to the code as below:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const streamifier = require('streamifier');
    const multipart = require('parse-multipart');
    const azureStorage = require('azure-storage');

    var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
    var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
    var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);

    var filedata = parts[0].data;         // Image buffer data
    var filename = parts[0].filename; 

    var a=azureStorage.createBlobService('xxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxx');
    try {
        var b= a.createBlockBlobFromStream('container', filename, streamifier.createReadStream(new Buffer (filedata)), filedata.length,(err, result)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("Image upload failed", err);
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

I send image using Postman:

[image]

And after uploading image to portal, the blob content is `application/octet-stream` and I can download it and view it successfully.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@rkmusic75/uploading-image-multipart-to-azure-blob-from-azure-functions-streamifier-parse-multipart-79d9d679adef).

**Update:**

The `azure-storage` library and "new Buffer" are both out of date. Refer to the code using `@azure/storage-blob`.

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { config } from "../cosmos/config";
import { BlobServiceClient, BlockBlobUploadStreamOptions } from "@azure/storage-blob";
const streamifier = require("streamifier");
const multipart = require("parse-multipart");

export const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    const storageConnectionString = config.storageConnectionString;

    // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);

    // Create a unique name for the container
    const containerName = config.storageContainerName;

    // Get a reference to a container
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    // Gets the file name from the url, could be a bug if you want the filename from the file contents
    const blobName = context.bindingData.imageName;

    // Get a block blob client
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    if (req.method === "POST")
    {
      const bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
      const boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
      const parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);
      const filedata = parts[0].data;
      const filename = parts[0].filename;
      const options: BlockBlobUploadStreamOptions = {};
      try
      {
        const result = await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(streamifier.createReadStream(Buffer.from(filedata)), filedata.length);
        context.res = { status: 200 };
        return;
      }
      catch(err)
      {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    context.res = { status: 302, headers: { "location": blockBlobClient.url }, body: null};

};
```

Comment: I was able to make it work with this solution so thank you! I noticed that azure-storage is out of date relative to the azure/storage-blob. I was able to tweak yours to get it to work with azure/storage-blob.

Comment: The azure-storage library and "new Buffer" are both out of date. If you can update your answer to what I wrote using @azure/storage-blob, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Joey Cai and @evilSnobu's answers I was able to get it to work using parse-multipart and streamifier.

```
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import { config } from "../cosmos/config";
import { BlobServiceClient, BlockBlobUploadStreamOptions } from "@azure/storage-blob";
const streamifier = require("streamifier");
const multipart = require("parse-multipart");

export const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    const storageConnectionString = config.storageConnectionString;

    // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(storageConnectionString);

    // Create a unique name for the container
    const containerName = config.storageContainerName;

    // Get a reference to a container
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    // Gets the file name from the url, could be a bug if you want the filename from the file contents
    const blobName = context.bindingData.imageName;

    // Get a block blob client
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);

    if (req.method === "POST")
    {
      const bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
      const boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
      const parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);
      const filedata = parts[0].data;
      const filename = parts[0].filename;
      const options: BlockBlobUploadStreamOptions = {};
      try
      {
        const result = await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(streamifier.createReadStream(Buffer.from(filedata)), filedata.length);
        context.res = { status: 200 };
        return;
      }
      catch(err)
      {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    context.res = { status: 302, headers: { "location": blockBlobClient.url }, body: null};

};
```

Comment: Got `streamifier.createReadStream is not a function`